Unexpected Result When Using TPerlRegEx Replace in Delphi 2010
I'm working with Delphi 2010 and using the TPerlRegEx library for regular expression matching and replacing. I encountered an issue while attempting to replace the first character in a string.
Here's a simplified example of my code:
var
  lpReg: TPerlRegEx;
begin
  lpReg := TPerlRegEx.Create;
  try
    lpReg.Options := lpReg.Options + [preCaseLess];
    lpReg.Subject := 'aabb';
    lpReg.RegEx := '^a';
    lpReg.Replacement := '';
    lpReg.ReplaceAll;
    Result := string(lpReg.Subject);
  finally
    lpReg.Free;
  end;
end;

Expected Result: 'abb'
Actual Result: 'bb'
It seems that the ^a pattern is replacing both leading 'a' characters instead of just the first one. The ReplaceAll call appears to be replacing all matches, not just the first occurrence as intended.
Am I misusing the ReplaceAll method, or is there a configuration I'm overlooking? Any insights into what might be causing this behavior would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance!
The ReplaceAll method has gone through multiple loops. I have found that '^a' will be matched again after one loop. This is because I replaced the first character with an empty string. If it is replaced with a non-empty string, this problem will not occur. It is necessary to perform loop matching. Otherwise, if my target string is 'abcabcabc' and the string pattern is 'ab', it will only replace 'ab' once.
The following is the code for the ReplaceAll function in Pascal:
function TPerlRegEx.ReplaceAll: Boolean;
begin
  if Match then begin
    Result := True;
    repeat
      Replace
    until not MatchAgain;
  end
  else Result := False;
end;

I hope this method is universal and can match correctly with or without anchor '^', Thank you!
For completeness, I should mention that if I don't use replaceAll, it will only match once. However, I need a universal effect that can match a pattern not starting with ^ multiple times and can also correctly match a pattern starting with ^.
Example 1: The pattern is 'a', and the target string is 'aabbaaba'. The replacement string is an empty string. The correct output should be 'bbb', replacing five 'a's with an empty string. When I use replace, the output result is 'abbaaba', which is incorrect. Only when using replaceAll can the correct result 'bbb' be obtained.
Example 2: The pattern is '^a', and the target string is 'aabb'. The replacement string is an empty string. The correct output should be 'abb', only replacing one 'a'. When I use replace, the output result is 'abb', which is correct. When using replaceAll, the output result is 'bb', which is incorrect.
Please refer to: https://github.com/TheDelphiCoder/PerlRegEx/blob/master/PerlRegEx.pas.

Yeah, looks like ReplaceAll replaces until no match is found, which is wrong. You can use the same workaround as in Notepad++, i.e. replace ^a(.*) (or ^a([\w\W]*)) with $1.

The method is working as intended - it's just not your way of intention. If you want a different outcome you can easily write your own function/method which operates on .Match() and .MatchAgain(), advancing through the characters and providing only portions of text to match next.

I'd add that the recursive nature of the method is not something a regular user would expect. It would be great if the recursion could be triggered with an additional argument, while being set to false by default.

Why are you calling ReplaceAll?

when I use replace, it can only replace the first occurrence. I'm looking for a solution that can achieve multiple replacements without relying on replaceAll and also handle patterns starting with '^' correctly.

In some systems ReplaceAll functionality is iterative (not recursive). It looks for the first occurrence and (if found) replaces it. Next it searches again starting after the replacement text, replacing and searching until no more occurrences are found. For replacing ^a with nothing in aabb I expect the first search and replace to yield abb, the second search finds an a at the start of the string and so replaces that, leaving just the bb.

One might argue that the start-of-string should be consumed by the first replace, but maybe not in this implementation. Just tried it in Notepad++ version 8.7, both a characters are removed by ReplaceAll. Also tried in C# where Regex.Replace only removed one a.
